Blender Rigging Weightpaint Not Working
I am working on a model megalodon shark for a animation project but can't rig the model. I have been trying to fix it for about a month but its not worked.
When I tried to use automatic weightpainting on my models rig it didn't work so I attempted to manually weightpaint on the model however when I finished and tried to move the rig it all became stretched. You can see that where I weightpainted and where I move the rig it doesn't smooth out to the rest of the model.
I can't add the file as it is way to large, the subdivision surface modifier has been applied as that's what the tutorial showed.
I have been following Critical Giant's guide on making a Trex.
Any help will be greatly appreciated, thankyou and enjoy the rest of your day.


hello please share your file, i suspect you have too many vertices, also put the Armature modifier above the Subdivision Surface modifier?

Rigging can be tough. Here are a few quick tips to help:
Check Mesh: Ensure no overlapping vertices or disconnected parts.
Recalculate Normals: In Edit Mode, select all A and press Shift+N.
Automatic Weights: Ensure bones are correctly placed and scaled. Simplify the mesh if needed.
Manual Weight Paint: Use larger brushes first, then refine. Use the Blur tool for smooth transitions.
Bone Envelopes: Enable Envelope in the Armature modifier and adjust bone radii.
Modifier Order: Ensure the Armature modifier is above Subdivision Surface in the stack.
Normalize Weights: Use Normalize All to fix weight issues.
